# Memory usage increases with every reload of intent in Android. Why?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have an activity/intent in which a text file (which contains a JSON array) is read from the device.
On every reload another row from the array is being processes.
The text file isn't that large (20 Kb) and is being downloaded in the MainActivity together with some images (up to 50) which are between 20 and 70 Kb.

Everytime the intent is reloaded and another row is processes, another image is being loaded into an ImageView. Also several TextViews are updated with Strings that are read from the JSON array.

The issue is that with every reload of the intent, the memory usage increases with about 1 Mb.

I show this through the use of:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long usedMemory=runtime.totalMemory() / (1024 * 1024);
```

The Bitmap is recycled, 
BufferedWriter is closed,
FileInputStream is closed,
BufferedReader is closed and
InputStreamReader is closed

What am I missing that causes the memory usage to increase?

This is the code form the Activity:

```
public class LoadRaaplijstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView locatieText;
    private TextView totaalText;
    private TextView inhoudText;
    private TextView descriptionText;
    private TextView eanText;
    private TextView ditpadText;
    private TableLayout layout16;
    private TableLayout layout32;
    private Button raapbuttonNext;

    private Menu menu;
    private Toast toast;

    private String next;
    private String prev;
    private String deze;
    private String ean;
    private String foto;
    private String description;
    private String voorraad;
    private String totaal;
    private String inhoud;
    private JSONArray bakken;
    private int aantalbakken;
    private String einde = "";
    private String loadeinde = "0";
    private String picked;
    private String locatie;
    private String locatiepadclean;
    private String locatiemeterclean;
    private String locatieplankclean;
    private String locatievakjeclean;
    private String pijl;
    private String totaalditpad;

    private String batch;
    private String kar;
    private String raper;
    private String afmaken;

    String spinneridSelected;
    String spinnerkarSelected;
    String spinnerraperSelected;
    String radioAfmakenSelected;

    Bitmap myBitmap;

    ArrayList<Integer> gehadArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    //JSON array
    private JSONArray raaplijstresult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_raaplijst);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        findViewById(R.id.productimage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.wificonnectie).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.probeeropnieuw).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.raapbuttonNext).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.raapbuttonPrev).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        raapbuttonNext     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.raapbuttonNext);
        raapbuttonNext.setFocusable(true);
        raapbuttonNext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        raapbuttonNext.requestFocus();

        locatieText     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locatieText);
        totaalText      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totaalText);
        inhoudText      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inhoudText);
        eanText         = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eanText);
        ditpadText      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ditpadTxt);
        descriptionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        layout16 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout16);
        layout32 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout32);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        spinneridSelected = intent.getStringExtra("spinneridSelected");
        spinnerkarSelected = intent.getStringExtra("spinnerkarSelected");
        spinnerraperSelected = intent.getStringExtra("spinnerraperSelected");
        radioAfmakenSelected = intent.getStringExtra("radioAfmakenSelected");
        deze = intent.getStringExtra("load");

        batch   = spinneridSelected;
        kar     = spinnerkarSelected;
        raper   = spinnerraperSelected;
        afmaken = radioAfmakenSelected;

        if(afmaken.equals("ja")){

            deze = getLaatstgehad();
        }

        Integer gehad = Integer.parseInt(deze.toString());

        gehadArray = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra("gehadArray");

        if(!gehadArray.contains(gehad)) {
            try {
                gehadArray.add(gehad);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
            }
        }else{
            locatieText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        saveGehad();

        getRaaplijstRegel();

    }

    private void saveGehad() {
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Raaplijst");

        File file = new File(dir, "/gehad.txt");
        if(file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {

            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            buf.write(deze.toString());
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getLaatstgehad() {
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Raaplijst");

        File file = new File(dir, "/gehad.txt");
        String ret = deze;
        if(file.exists()){
            try {
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream (file);

                if ( inputStream != null ) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                    String receiveString = "";
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                        stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    }
                    inputStreamReader.close();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    String gehadFromFile = stringBuilder.toString();
                    ret = gehadFromFile;
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            ret = deze;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public void loadPrev (View view){
        loadRaaplijstPrev();
    }

    public void loadRaaplijstPrev (){

                if (prev.equals("-1")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GratisProducten.class);

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                    extras.putString("spinneridSelected", batch);
                    extras.putString("spinnerkarSelected", kar);
                    extras.putString("spinnerraperSelected", raper);
                    extras.putString("radioAfmakenSelected", "nee");
                    extras.putIntegerArrayList("gehadArray", gehadArray);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }  else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadRaaplijstActivity.class);

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("load", prev);
                    extras.putString("spinneridSelected", batch);
                    extras.putString("spinnerkarSelected", kar);
                    extras.putString("spinnerraperSelected", raper);
                    extras.putString("radioAfmakenSelected","nee");
                    extras.putIntegerArrayList("gehadArray", gehadArray);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }        
    }

    public void loadBegin (View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

    public void loadBegin(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void loadNext (View view){
        loadRaaplijstNext();
    }

    public void loadRaaplijstNext (){

                if (loadeinde.equals("1")) {
                    loadEnd();
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadRaaplijstActivity.class);

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("spinneridSelected", batch);
                    extras.putString("spinnerkarSelected", kar);
                    extras.putString("spinnerraperSelected", raper);
                    extras.putString("radioAfmakenSelected","nee");
                    extras.putString("load", next);
                    extras.putIntegerArrayList("gehadArray", gehadArray);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
    }

    public void loadEnd(){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("einde", einde);
            extras.putString("load", deze);
            extras.putString("spinneridSelected", batch);
            extras.putString("spinnerkarSelected", kar);
            extras.putString("spinnerraperSelected", raper);
            extras.putString("radioAfmakenSelected", "nee");
            extras.putIntegerArrayList("gehadArray", gehadArray);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

    }

    private String readRaaplijstFromFile() {

        String ret = "Raaplijst niet gevonden";

        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Raaplijst");

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream (new File(dir + "/raaplijstJSON.txt"));

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
                inputStreamReader.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private void getRaaplijstRegel(){
            String raaplijstJson = readRaaplijstFromFile();

            if(raaplijstJson.equals("Raaplijst niet gevonden")){
            }else{

                try {
                    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(raaplijstJson);

                    raaplijstresult = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY_RAAPLIJST);

                    getRegel(raaplijstresult);

                } catch (JSONException e) {StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    String stacktrace = sw.toString();
                    writeExceptionToFile(stacktrace);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }

    private void getRegel(JSONArray j) {
        for (int h = 0; h < j.length(); h++) {

            try {
                JSONObject sorteerObj = j.getJSONObject(h);

                JSONArray sorteer = sorteerObj.getJSONArray("sorteer");

                int i = Integer.parseInt(deze);
                try {
                    JSONObject json = sorteer.getJSONObject(i);

                    einde = json.getString("einde");

                    loadeinde = json.getString("loadeinde");
                    if(loadeinde.equals("1")){
                        loadEnd();
                    }

                    ean = json.getString("ean");
                    eanText.setText("EAN: " + ean);

                    locatie = json.getString("locatie");
                    locatieText.setText(locatie);

                    locatiepadclean = json.getString("locatiepad");
                    if(locatiepadclean.equals("leeg")){
                        locatiepadclean = "";
                    }

                    locatiemeterclean = json.getString("locatiemeter");

                    if(locatiemeterclean.equals("leeg")){
                        locatiemeterclean = "";
                    }

                    locatieplankclean = json.getString("locatieplank");
                    if(locatieplankclean.equals("leeg")){
                        locatieplankclean = "";
                    }

                    locatievakjeclean = json.getString("locatievakje");
                    if(locatievakjeclean.equals("leeg")){
                        locatievakjeclean = "";
                    }

                    picked = json.getString("picked");

                    if(picked.equals("1")) {
                        locatieText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }

                    foto = json.getString("foto");

                    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Raaplijst");
                    File imgFile = new  File(dir + "/" + foto);

                    if(imgFile.exists()){

                        if (myBitmap != null) {
                            myBitmap.recycle();
                            myBitmap = null;
                        }

                        myBitmap = decodeFile(imgFile, 231, 231);

                        ImageView bindImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.productimage);

                        bindImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                    }else{
                        toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imgFile.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 20);
                        toast.show();
                    }

                    findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.productimage).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    description = json.getString("description");
                    descriptionText.setText(description);

                    voorraad = json.getString("voorraad");

                    aantalbakken = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("aantalbakken"));

                    if(aantalbakken == 32){
                        findViewById(R.id.layout16).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.layout32).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.layout32).setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(LoadRaaplijstActivity.this) {
                            public void onSwipeTop() {

                            }

                            public void onSwipeRight() {
                                loadRaaplijstPrev();
                            }

                            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                                loadRaaplijstNext();
                            }

                            public void onSwipeBottom() {

                            }

                        });
                    }else{
                        findViewById(R.id.layout32).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.layout16).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.layout16).setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(LoadRaaplijstActivity.this) {
                            public void onSwipeTop() {

                            }

                            public void onSwipeRight() {
                                loadRaaplijstPrev();
                            }

                            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                                loadRaaplijstNext();
                            }

                            public void onSwipeBottom() {

                            }

                        });
                    }

                    int b = 0;
                    int[] textViewIds;
                    int[] bakdrawables;

                    if(aantalbakken == 32) {
                        textViewIds = new int[]{R.id.b32, R.id.b33, R.id.b34, R.id.b35, R.id.b36, R.id.b37, R.id.b38, R.id.b39,
                                R.id.b40, R.id.b41, R.id.b42, R.id.b43, R.id.b44, R.id.b45, R.id.b46, R.id.b47,
                                R.id.b48, R.id.b49, R.id.b50, R.id.b51, R.id.b52, R.id.b53, R.id.b54, R.id.b55,
                                R.id.b56, R.id.b57, R.id.b58, R.id.b59, R.id.b60, R.id.b61, R.id.b62, R.id.b63
                        };

                        bakdrawables = new int[]{R.drawable.vbbb1, R.drawable.vbbb2, R.drawable.vbbb3, R.drawable.vbbb4, R.drawable.vbbb5, R.drawable.vbbb6, R.drawable.vbbb7, R.drawable.vbbb8,
                                R.drawable.vbbb9, R.drawable.vbbb10, R.drawable.vbbb11, R.drawable.vbbb12, R.drawable.vbbb13, R.drawable.vbbb14, R.drawable.vbbb15, R.drawable.vbbb16,
                                R.drawable.vbbb17, R.drawable.vbbb18, R.drawable.vbbb19, R.drawable.vbbb20, R.drawable.vbbb21, R.drawable.vbbb22, R.drawable.vbbb23, R.drawable.vbbb24,
                                R.drawable.vbbb25, R.drawable.vbbb26, R.drawable.vbbb27, R.drawable.vbbb28, R.drawable.vbbb29, R.drawable.vbbb30, R.drawable.vbbb31, R.drawable.vbbb32
                        };
                    }else{
                        textViewIds = new int[]{R.id.b16, R.id.b17, R.id.b18, R.id.b19,
                                R.id.b20, R.id.b21, R.id.b22, R.id.b23,
                                R.id.b24, R.id.b25, R.id.b26, R.id.b27,
                                R.id.b28, R.id.b29, R.id.b30, R.id.b31
                        };

                        bakdrawables = new int[]{R.drawable.vbb1, R.drawable.vbb2, R.drawable.vbb3, R.drawable.vbb4, R.drawable.vbb5, R.drawable.vbb6, R.drawable.vbb7, R.drawable.vbb8,
                                R.drawable.vbb9, R.drawable.vbb10, R.drawable.vbb11, R.drawable.vbb12, R.drawable.vbb13, R.drawable.vbb14, R.drawable.vbb15, R.drawable.vbb16
                        };
                    }

                    for (int z = 0; z < aantalbakken; z++) {
                        String prefixbakdrawable = "vbb";

                        if(aantalbakken == 32){
                            prefixbakdrawable = "vbbb";
                        }

                        Integer inhoudBak = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("b" + z));
                        if (inhoudBak > 0) {
                            ((TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[z])).setText(inhoudBak.toString());
                            ((TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[z])).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                            findViewById(textViewIds[z]).setBackgroundResource(bakdrawables[z]);
                        } else {
                            ((TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[z])).setText(" ");
                        }
                    }

                    totaal = json.getString("totaal");
                    totaalText.setText(totaal);

                    inhoud = json.getString("inhoud");
                    inhoudText.setText(inhoud);

                    prev = json.getString("prev");

                    next = json.getString("next");

                    pijl = json.getString("pijl");

                    if(pijl.equals("left")){
                        locatieText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.left);
                    }

                    totaalditpad = json.getString("totaalditpad");
                    ditpadText.setText(totaalditpad);

                    if (sorteerObj.has("bakken")) {
                        bakken = sorteerObj.getJSONArray("bakken");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                String stacktrace = sw.toString();
                writeExceptionToFile(stacktrace);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale*=2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    public void probeerOpnieuw (View v){
        loadAgain("ja");
    }

    public void loadAgain(String doorgaan) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoadRaaplijstActivity.class);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("load", deze);
        extras.putString("spinneridSelected", batch);
        extras.putString("spinnerkarSelected", kar);
        extras.putString("spinnerraperSelected", raper);
        extras.putString("radioAfmakenSelected", doorgaan);
        extras.putIntegerArrayList("gehadArray", gehadArray);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_load_raaplijst, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        String headerTxtTxt = "Batch: " + batch + "- Kar: " + kar + "- Raper: " + raper;

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        long maxMemory=runtime.maxMemory() / (1024 * 1024);
        long usedMemory=(runtime.totalMemory() / (1024 * 1024)) - (runtime.freeMemory() / (1024 * 1024));

        if(!Config.DEBUG.equals("")) headerTxtTxt = headerTxtTxt + " MaxMem:" + maxMemory + "Mb CurMem:" + usedMemory;
        setTitle(headerTxtTxt);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.stopraaplijst:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

                Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:

                loadAgain(radioAfmakenSelected);
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

                loadRaaplijstPrev();
                return true;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

                loadRaaplijstNext();
                return true;

            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void writeExceptionToFile(String exception){
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(
                new Date());

        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Lograaplijst");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        File file = new File(dir, "log_h_" + formattedDate + "_" + batch + "_" +  kar + ".txt");

        try {
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            buf.append(currentDateTimeString + ":" + exception.toString());
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try - https://github.com/square/leakcanary. Also use https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html